# matching the value of the string in a same line but not in a different line

Tags: python

From the below output I want to get the value of port description.

```
out = """Port Description - not advertised
         System Name - not advertised"""
```

As of now i am using the below code:

```
re.search(r'Port Description\s+-\s+([\s\w]+)',out).group(1)
```

But the result I am getting: `not advertised System Name`

I want only `not advertised` in my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search in the multiline mode (`flags=re.M`) and include the end-of-line marker `'$'`:

```
re.search(r'Port Description\s+-\s+([\s\w]+$)', out, flags=re.M).group(1)
#'not advertised'
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. it is working but i am hgetting the output as below

Comment: i am getting the output as 'not advertised\n'. i dont want the \n also in my output

Comment: Then strip it off. But actually I am surprised that you are seeing a '\n'. It should have been eliminated.

Comment: cannot we do by using regex itself?

Comment: As I said in the modified comment, the regex must not have matched the line break. I cannot reproduce your result. Are you perhaps using different data?